# mysql Japanese shows as ä¸€äºº

Tags: mysql, laravel, cjk

A big problem that I hope is still fixable.
I recently received a .sql file that has Japanese in it.

All characters are set like

```
ä¸€äºº
```

Have checked the database and its utf8, but my laravel project now also shows
the same characters. Is there a way to convert this back to Japanese in the database, or on the laravel website?
I have tried a bunch of things with the utf8 meta tags, but this doesn't worked.

EDIT;
Have checked the charset from the database and table, they both say utf8

Thank you.

Comment: check your table charset, is it  utf8 also.

Comment: @umefarooq [That would be wrong](https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-mysql-never-use-utf8-use-utf8mb4-11761243e434). Please restrict your answers to the answer section where they can be peer reviewed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql connection collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and also Database collation too `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

The below code is for Laravel:

```
  'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
  'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, Have tryed it, gives an error ERROR 1115 (42000): Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'

Comment: your general server connection collation is "utf8mb4_unicode_ci" and your table collation is "utf8mb4_unicode_ci" too and you setup the laravel's database config too but having that error?

Comment: Database originally didn't come from laravel, just building it to a laravel application.

Comment: First you set the general connection collaction and after that you set the Database collation but having that error?

Comment: This error comes when I try to update the mariaDB from the comment line. MariaDB [learning]> ALTER TABLE kanji CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ERROR 1115 (42000): Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci', in laravel i replaced the charset and collation, this doesnt give anerror

Answer (score 0):

Have converted the Japanese back to normal
It took some time to find a solution, but it works,

```
UPDATE kanji SET characters = 
CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(characters USING latin1) USING utf8);
```

This worked for me.

Comment: [Do not use `utf8`](https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-mysql-never-use-utf8-use-utf8mb4-11761243e434).

Comment: This works for me! Database is working again and updated

Comment: You should read the article. Study it. Understand it. Then start using `utf8mb4`.

Comment: Like that, I read over the link. Thanks reading it now. Have also tried updating the database with utf8mb4, but this results in ?????, utf8 is at this moment the only option that really worked.

Comment: You must have done something wrong. Will just say it one more time: `utf8mb4` is what you should be using, for the reasons laid out in the article. `utf8` is broken, period, full stop. It may appear to work for you today but it will cause you grief later. Don't let it.